# How to detect UIViewController originalContentView size changes properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, iad

In order to detect `originalContentView` size change events (including both device rotation events and ad banner displaying/not displaying), I'm currently overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    CGSize newSize = self.originalContentView.frame.size;
    if((newSize.width != _viewSize.width) || (newSize.height != _viewSize.height)){
        _viewSize = newSize;
        //size change event => take the necessary steps
    }
}
```

Where `_viewSize` is a non public property I added to my view controller to detect size changes.

`-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id)coordinator` doesn't match my need since it detects only device rotation events, and the size parameter never considers whether the ad banner is displaying.

My current approach is more of a workaround though, so is there a proper way to detect originalContentView size change events?

Comment: What is originalContentView?

Comment: @markov see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/originalContentView).